# How does alpha blending work, mathematically, pixel-by-pixel?

Tags: math, colors, shader, pixel, alphablending

Seems like it's not as simple as RGB1*A1 + RGB2*A2...how are values clipped?  Weighted?  Etc.

And is this a context-dependent question?  Are there different algorithms, that produce different results?  Or one standard implementation?

I'm particularly interested in OpenGL-specific answers, but context from other environments is useful too.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_blending#Alpha_blending

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about OpenGL, but one pixel of opacity A is usually drawn on another pixel like so:

```
result.r = background.r * (1 - A) + foreground.r * A
result.g = background.g * (1 - A) + foreground.g * A
result.b = background.b * (1 - A) + foreground.b * A
```

Repeat this operation for multiple pixels.

Answer (score 7):

The above answer works if the image isn't premultiplied alpha. However if you use that type of blending with a premultiplied alpha image, there will be a black border.

**Premultiplied Alpha:**

When the image is created, the color values are multiplied by the alpha channel. Take a look at this one pixel example:

```
Pixel: r = 1, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0.5
```

When it's saved, the rgb vales will be multiplied by the alpha value giving:

```
Pixel: r = 0.5, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0.5
```

To blend this kind of image you need to use the following formula:

```
result.r = background.r * (1 - A) + foreground.r
result.g = background.g * (1 - A) + foreground.g
result.b = background.b * (1 - A) + foreground.b
```

**Non-premultiplied Alpha**

In this example, the alpha channel is completely separate to the color channels.

```
Pixel: r = 1, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0.5
```

When it's saved:

```
Pixel: r = 1, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0.5
```

It's the same. In this case the answer provided by minitech is correct.

More details can be found here: [Premultiplied alpha](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre)