# Canvas transparent fillStyle does not fully cover existing content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If a canvas fillStyle is transparent and it is applied repeatedly, it does not cover the existing content fully, unless the fillStyle color is black or white.

You can see a fiddle at the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/tgovrqhj/1/

```
<canvas id="black"></canvas>
<canvas id="grey"></canvas>
<canvas id="white"></canvas>

new Box("black", "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)");
new Box("grey", "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)", "rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.05)");
new Box("white", "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)");

function Box(canvasId, textColor, overlayColor) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = textColor;
    context.font = "50px Arial";
    context.fillText("Text", 90, 80);

    setInterval(draw, 50);

    function draw() {
    context.fillStyle = overlayColor;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
}
```

There are 3 boxes, each with green text. They are each covered with a fillStyle of 0.05 opacity; the first with black, the second with grey and the last one with white.

Only the white and black fillStyles cover the text completely, other colors do not.

Why is this disparity and is there a way to make the transparent fillStyle applied repeatedly to fully cover the existing content.

Comment: It is strange Increase the opacity to higher value (0.5 for example) can be a workaround.

Comment: It's normal, that's how [alpha blending works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768836/how-does-alpha-blending-work-mathematically-pixel-by-pixel). Note that neither the black nor the white version are truly covered either. They're harder to notice, but still have ghosts.

Comment: @LoredraL For my current specific use case, I need the overlay opacity low (0.05), I cannot increase it so much to 0.5.

Comment: @AncientRo : For your case, if the goal is the transition of color, you can use alpha as variable and increase them by 0.05 inside drawing iteration. Something like  
  alpha+=0.05;
  overlayColor="rgba(100, 0, 0,"+alpha+")"

Comment: I think what you are trying to do (because I've done it before) is trying to overlay semitransparent shapes so that each time the shape is drawn it changes by the same amount to your semitransparent color. The math is complicated, but the way to do it is to choose opacities that are a power of two, like [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ytq948ew/). In that example you can see the shading go from lime to black with the first fill having an opacity of 0.0625.